# Google Chart Tooltip Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, json, google-visualization

I am currently working on Google Chart using ASP.NET and connecting it to the database (SQL Server). But I have a problem when trying to customize the tool tip.

Here's Header Code:

```
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('1.1', { 'packages': ['bar'] });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'sample_page.aspx/GetChartData',
            data: '{}',
            success: function (response) {
                drawchart(response.d); // calling method
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("Error Loading Data");
            }
        });
    })

    function drawchart(dataValues) {
        // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
        // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
        // draws it.

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('BarChartsDIV'));
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'customer');
        data.addColumn('number', 'percent_submitted')
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});


        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].customer,
            { v: dataValues[i].percent_submitted, f: dataValues[i].percent_submitted+ '%'},'TEST TOOL TIP']);
        }

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1, 2]);

        chart.draw(view,
          {
              tooltip: { isHtml: true},
              title: "",
              legend: { position: 'none' },
              bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
              axes: {
                  x: {
                      0: { side: 'top', label: '' }, // Top x-axis.
                  },
                  y: {
                      0: { label: '' } //Side y-axis
                  }

              },
              bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },

          });
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, the tool tip doesn't work. Only the Customer Name and the Percentage display on the tool tip.

[Sample Generated Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STsTi.png)

Comment: What do you want the tooltip to display?

Comment: @MarcusH Hi marcus, I would like to display customer, submit percentage and tool tip 1

Comment: Does it work if you just write the chart after the loop? put "chart.draw(data);" after the end of the loop and comment out the part after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unfortunately, [Column Roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles), including tooltips,  don't work with *Material* charts, only *Core*

*Material* --> `packages: ['bar']` + `google.charts.Bar`

*Core* --> `packages: ['corechart']` + `google.visualization.BarChart`

you can use the following configuration option to get *Core* close to the look & feel of *Material*

`theme: 'material'`

**note 1**: when using a tooltip column, all of the tooltip content must be provided, it doesn't append anything to the default tooltip

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // simulate data
    dataValues = [
      {
        customer: 'Customer A',
        percent_submitted: 10
      },
      {
        customer: 'Customer B',
        percent_submitted: 20
      },
      {
        customer: 'Customer C',
        percent_submitted: 30
      },
    ];

    drawchart(dataValues);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawchart(dataValues) {
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('BarChartsDIV'));
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'customer');
    data.addColumn('number', 'percent_submitted')
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});


    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].customer,
        { v: dataValues[i].percent_submitted, f: dataValues[i].percent_submitted + '%'},
        dataValues[i].customer + '\nTEST TOOL TIP\n' + dataValues[i].percent_submitted + '%']);
    }

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, 2]);

    chart.draw(view,
      {
          theme: 'material',
          tooltip: { isHtml: true},
          title: "",
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
              x: {
                  0: { side: 'top', label: '' }, // Top x-axis.
              },
              y: {
                  0: { label: '' } //Side y-axis
              }

          },
          bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },

      });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="BarChartsDIV"></div>
```

**note 2**: for HTML tooltips to work, you must include a column property

`data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // simulate data
    dataValues = [
      {
        customer: 'Customer A',
        percent_submitted: 10
      },
      {
        customer: 'Customer B',
        percent_submitted: 20
      },
      {
        customer: 'Customer C',
        percent_submitted: 30
      },
    ];

    drawchart(dataValues);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawchart(dataValues) {
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('BarChartsDIV'));
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'customer');
    data.addColumn('number', 'percent_submitted')
    // include column property for html tooltips
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});


    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].customer,
        { v: dataValues[i].percent_submitted, f: dataValues[i].percent_submitted + '%'},
        // need to include own styling as well
        '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + dataValues[i].customer + '<div>TEST TOOL TIP</div><div>' + dataValues[i].percent_submitted + '%</div></div>']);
    }

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, 2]);

    chart.draw(view,
      {
          theme: 'material',
          tooltip: { isHtml: true},
          title: "",
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
              x: {
                  0: { side: 'top', label: '' }, // Top x-axis.
              },
              y: {
                  0: { label: '' } //Side y-axis
              }

          },
          bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },

      });
}
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="BarChartsDIV"></div>
```

**note 3**: as for *Material* charts, they show the formatted value (`f:`) by default, so you could add a bit of text there, or at the end of the column headings, which would be for all rows

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // simulate data
    dataValues = [
      {
        customer: 'Customer A',
        percent_submitted: 10
      },
      {
        customer: 'Customer B',
        percent_submitted: 20
      },
      {
        customer: 'Customer C',
        percent_submitted: 30
      },
    ];

    drawchart(dataValues);
  },
  packages: ['bar']
});

function drawchart(dataValues) {
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('BarChartsDIV'));
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'customer');
    data.addColumn('number', 'percent_submitted \n OTHER TOOLTIP TEXT FOR ALL ROWS')

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].customer,
        { v: dataValues[i].percent_submitted, f: dataValues[i].percent_submitted + '% TEST TOOL TIP'}]);
    }

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1]);

    chart.draw(view,
      {
          tooltip: { isHtml: true},
          title: "",
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
              x: {
                  0: { side: 'top', label: '' }, // Top x-axis.
              },
              y: {
                  0: { label: '' } //Side y-axis
              }

          },
          bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },

      });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="BarChartsDIV"></div>
```

**note 4**: although not recommended, it is possible to modify the tooltip manually via SVG DOM, when the chart's `'ready'` event fires...

Comment: Can you elaborate and show how to get bar different colors ? thanks, i tried your working code but stack in setting the bar colors

Comment: Thank you, the v: and f: hint was _really_ helpful

Answer (score 0):

Adding to note.

**note 5:**

You can only modify `tooltip` if you use `google.visualization` like so:

```
new google.visualization.LineChart(divChart).draw(dataTable,options);
```

Not `google.charts`:

```
new google.charts.Line(divChart).draw(dataTable,options);
```

But, make sure to include `theme: 'material'` in the options of `google.visualization` to modernize the theme.

Answer (score -2):

I need to give credit to Catherine Manzo on the Google Charts Form for figuring this out.  Remove **focusTarget** from the chart Options and bingo!!

> Catherine Manzo said: I finally went back and compared the html code
>   for my new charts with ones made over the summer, when the tooltip
>   worked.  I realized there was an extra attribute in the newer code
>   (focusTarget) and when I deleted it, the tooltip function began
>   working again! The attribute to delete is highlighted in the code
>   below:

```
chart.opts = {title:"Company Performance",titlePosition:"out",focusTarget:"default",colors:['#66CDAA','#E0FFFF'],pointShape:"circle",hAxis: {format:"$ #,###.##",textPosition:"default",title:"In Thousands",slantedText:true,viewWindowMode:"default"},tooltip:{isHtml:false}};
```