# Google Charts fractionDigits

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I have a problem. Im relatively new to Javascript but I am working on a project where people want to have charts about their improvements. I have sucessfuly made 2 charts, while I do have problems for the 3rd one. The numbers consist of 0.000yyyyy when y stands for random numbers, and when you hover the chart, info shows 0. I put fractionDigits in options, but cant get them to work right.

Here is the code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor(transparent) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Xaurum Gold Growth');


  data.addRows([
[new Date(2015 , 03 , 15),0.000125],
[new Date(2015 , 04 , 09),0.000125202590875],
[new Date(2015, 04, 12), 0.000126019393875],

  ]);
var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time',
      textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
      titleTextStyle: {
    color: '#fff'
}
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Value',
      textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
      titleTextStyle: {
    color: '#fff'
}
    },
    legend: {
    textStyle: {color: '#fff'}
},
NumberFormat: {
  fractionDigits:15,
},
annotations: {
  boxStyle: {
    stroke: '#765e34',
    strokeWidth: 10,
  }
},
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    colors: ['#876c3c'],


  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('charta_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to format the number in the tooltip, use `NumberFormat`, after data is built

```
  // format data
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 15
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBackgroundColor,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawBackgroundColor(transparent) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Xaurum Gold Growth');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2015 , 03 , 15), 0.000125],
    [new Date(2015 , 04 , 09), 0.000125202590875],
    [new Date(2015, 04, 12), 0.000126019393875]
  ]);

  // format data
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 15
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time',
      textStyle:{
        color: '#FFF'
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Value',
      textStyle:{
        color: '#FFF'
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      textStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    annotations: {
      boxStyle: {
        stroke: '#765e34',
        strokeWidth: 10,
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    colors: ['#876c3c']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

before styling annotations, you must include an annotation column

use a DataView to add the column using a function to "stringify" the series column

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBackgroundColor,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawBackgroundColor(transparent) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Xaurum Gold Growth');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2015, 03, 15), 0.000125],
    [new Date(2015, 04, 09), 0.000125202590875],
    [new Date(2015, 04, 12), 0.000126019393875],
    [new Date(2015, 05, 22), 0.000126211199625],
    [new Date(2015, 06, 07), 0.000127017994375],
    [new Date(2015, 06, 08), 0.000127487763],
    [new Date(2015, 06, 09), 0.000128022515125],
    [new Date(2015, 06, 10), 0.00012886722975],
    [new Date(2015, 06, 11), 0.00012921927025],
  ]);

  // add annotation column
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 15
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time',
      textStyle: {
        color: '#FFF'
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Value',
      textStyle: {
        color: '#FFF'
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      textStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    annotations: {
      boxStyle: {
        stroke: '#876c3c',
        strokeWidth:3
      },
      textStyle: {
        color: '#876c3c'
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    colors: ['#876c3c']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('charta_div'));
  // use data view to draw chart
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="charta_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah I am trying my best to style annotations but as I said I'm pretty new to Javascript so I don't understand where to put all the stuff, I'd need to change background color, font color, border. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I think I am not doing something correctly, I have done hopefully as I should do, but I cant see anything happening, here is the jsfiddle example.
[link]https://jsfiddle.net/pprh2rot/1/[/link]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126293/discussion-between-podlipnik-and-whitehat).

Comment: I see, okay I wrote you that I was unclear, i said for annotations (which adds extra text to the chart) but I meant those pop-up boubles when you hover the chart, that shows you info, like Date, Title, Quantity/Value... Sorry that I was unclear, it was my mistake

Comment: hope you understand now what I mean

Comment: gotcha, those are tooltips, [here is a recent answer with examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40153880/5090771) -- let me know...

Comment: ohhh I didn't know how they were called... Let me try once I get to the computer and will let you know

Comment: sorry for late response, so basically I would have to add those new data values? Sorry for confusing you but I am really really new to JS and I have no clue.... I did some basics but thats all. Is there a chance that I do just something simple instead of writing 500 different data all over again?